# laravel Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::save() must be of the type array, object given

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an entity and each entity has an address.

I have 2 tables with relationship such as:

Entity:

```
protected $table = 'entities';
public $timestamps = true;

use Searchable;

public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address', 'entity_id');
}
```

Address:

```
protected $table = 'address';
public $timestamps = true;

public function entity()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Entity', 'id');
}
```

and my controller:

```
 public function update(EntityRequestUpdate $request)
    {
        $id = $request->input('entity_id');
        $entity = Entity::with('address')
            ->find($id);
        $entity->name = $request->input('name');
        $entity->type = $request->input('type');
        $entity->email = $request->input('email');
        $entity->twitter_entity = $request->input('twitter');
        $entity->facebook_entity = $request->input('facebook');
        $entity->instagram_entity = $request->input('instagram');
        $entity->google_places = $request->input('google');
        $entity->address->building_name = $request->input('address1');
        $entity->address->street = $request->input('address2');
        $entity->address->town = $request->input('town');
        $entity->address->city = $request->input('city');
        $entity->address->postcode = $request->input('postcode');
        $entity->address->telephone = $request->input('telephone');
        $entity->address->save($entity);
        $entity->save();

        $result = $entity->save();

        if($result){
            $message = 'success';
        }else{
            $message = 'error';
        }
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('message', $message);
    }
```

An error message is:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::save() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\Http\Controllers\EntityController.php on line 146

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to use `save()` method without any parameters. I have try it in `php artisan tinker` with same structure. And after I get same error, I try to remove the `$entity` parameter inside `save()` method:

```php
// After update, you should only use save() not save($entity)
$entity->address->save();
```

I hope I give correct answer for your problem :-D